# Bulletproof and random oracle model

Tags: random-oracle-model

I am trying to deal with Bulletproof. I can not find confirmation or refutation of the following assumption:

> Bulletproof cannot work without the random oracle, which is a
>   necessary part of the protocol.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Bulletproof are designed and proven in the ROM. What more do you need to know?

Comment: I guess he is asking about the validity of Bulletproof in the standard model.

Comment: Where did you encounter this quote/assumption? How is this question [different from your other one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76567/linkable-ring-signatures-from-ringct3-0-and-random-oracle-model)?

Comment: For @Maeher: I would like to know for what purpose the random oracle model in Bulletproof is used, at what stage this is happening and whether the use of the random oracle model is a necessary condition for the operation of Bulletproof.

Comment: For @Binou: and this too

Comment: For @EllaRose: 1) While reading a document; 2) RingCT3 uses Bulletproof, but it is not the same! RingCT3 can have its own oracles.

Comment: Do you understand what the random oracle model *is*?

Comment: @Maeher, I think, I understand pretty well, what the random oracle model is. I am talking about the application use of Bulletproof, or rather, the application of linked ring signatures based on Bulletproof, as it is done, for example, in RingCT3.0. Understanding why for what purpose the random oracle model in Bulletproof is used, at what stage this is happening and whether the use of the random oracle model is a necessary condition for the operation of Bulletproof can help to write more correct smart contracts acting as random oracles in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A core component of Bulletproof is a "range proof". Since Bulletproofs are designed to be used in the blockchain setting, it is important for the range proof to be non-interactive. The one used in Bulletproof is obtained by taking an interactive range proof and then compiling it into a non-interactive one using the [Fiat-Shamir transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat%E2%80%93Shamir_heuristic). The random oracle is used to establish the soundness of this transformed protocol. In practice one would instantiate this random oracle with a concrete hash function (say SHA-$3$).

Now, to answer your question whether a random oracle is necessary, it is not clear and is an active line of research. It has been shown that in some cases it is possible to instantiate the Fiat-Shamir transform with concrete hash functions (e.g., the recent construction of NIZK from LWE relies on such an instantiation of the Fiat-Shamir transform [PS19]).

[PS19]: Peikert and Sheihan [Non-Interactive Zero Knowledge for NP from (Plain) LWE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/158).